# Problem with jQuery's scrollTo

Tags: jquery, scroll, offset

I have a script doing a task much like a regular chat. Whenever I load new messages I fill a div like this:

```
....
<div class="conversation">
   <span class="sender">Sender: </span><span>Message sent by sender..</span>
</div>
....
```

Then, using jQuery I do something like this:

```
var lastOne = $("div.conversation:last", itemBox).offset();
itemBox.scrollTop(lastOne.top);
```

When I'm having a few (~40 messages) it works ok, but when the list grows too large, it starts calculating the offset wrong. This happens specially with large messages, taking over 3 lines. I'm not using any float inside the chat box (parent of all `div.conversation`), so I'm really shocked here...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can I ask what the 2nd argument in your code line is? What's `itemBox` in `$("div.conversation:last", itemBox).offset();`? I didn't know that you could pass 2 arguments to jquery when selecting..

Comment: The second argument is the context of the function. You can pass to jQuery that second argument and it will look for your search only inside the supplied context, if no context is supplied, the whole window is the context...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

I'm not much of a fan of doing this whole "answering my question" thing, but I'm less of a fan of leaving an open question. The position function does work on jQuery with some major browsers, but I haven't figured out why.. it dies with FFx 4, at the point I had to calculate the height of all the divs in the box, much like this:

```
var itemBox = $("#conversation5");
var loader = $("div.conversation", itemBox);
var sum = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < loader.length; i++)
   sum += $(loader[i]).innerHeight();

itemBox.scrollTop(sum);
```

It works flawlessly on all browsers, admitedly, not the prettiest solutions, but works nontheless.

Answer (score 3):

Try use `.position()` instead of `.offset()` if you can make it work for your needs.

http://api.jquery.com/position/

I've had a similiar problem with wrong offset calculations with jQuery

Comment: Problems has improved a bit, works better on IE, but stills looses track of the conversation on FF (testing with FF4)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try using [ViewPort](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport) ?